# Periodic DNS requests for network enabled document scanners

Tags: windows, networking, dns, scanner

Looking into a Wireshark capture, I noticed how my Windows machine (Win10) keeps sending DNS queries (type A) for two network enabled document printer/scanner devices. They come in about every 30s, two to four for each scanner, each request is retransmitted once and answered by a standard query response.

**ADDENDUM 2:** Interestingly, there is no subsequent IP traffic between the Windows machine and the document printer/scanner. There are only two groups of SNMP querries, each repeated every 10 minutes, one of which is initiated by the printer driver.

**ADDENDUM 1:** The setup consists of several Windows machines (mainly Win10), a RaspberryPi running dnsmasq among others, and two Brother printer/scanner devices (MFC-5460cn and MFC-5890cn). Both are setup using their respective Brother drivers (ver. 1.0.1.1 and 1.1.1.1). No other software (device monitor, control center, ...) has been installed.

This goes on for hours, even though none of the scanners is ever used. It stops when I disable them through the Windows devices manager. And the number of requests is drastically reduced if I set a large non-zero TTL for the DNS entries. But none of these is a satisfactory solution.

Why is Windows sending these DNS requests?
And how can I make it stop doing so?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "two network scanners"? I do not recognize this terminology. I think some more detail would also be useful, for instance, what DNS servers are listed for the machine?

Comment: @DanielK Sorry, I mean two multi function printer/scanner/fax devices which are connected via LAN.

Comment: I would be very suspicious of the device drivers and/or software for these devices. The software could be trying to maintain a session to these devices. It may be worth clarifying what vendor software you are using.

Comment: @DanielK We are talking about a Brother MFC-5460CN and a Brother MFC-5890CN. Both are configured using drivers supplied and signed by Brother.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use a DNS TTL value of zero.

For some servers a TTL of zero can mean "don't cache", but some other servers
may take zero to mean that the answer is expired and needs to be renewed.

Please explain why setting a non-zero TTL is not a satisfactory solution,
because it seems to me that it is the best solution.

Comment: dnsmasq's man page says: _This is the correct thing to do in almost all situations._ At least for local entries, zero TTL is the default setting. Setting a non-zero TTL is not satisfactory because it does not work (I still get these periodic queries) and it does not go to the core of the problem (Windows asking for the address of a device it is not supposed to use at that moment).

Comment: The dnsmasq man page does not apply to Windows where the behavior is different, as you have found out by now. It might also relate to the drivers of the devices, verifying that the devices are still available.

Comment: If Windows took a zero TTL meaning "entry expired", I would expect to see a difference with say 10s TTL. But I don't. What is more: There is far less IP traffic between the Windows machine and the scanner, than there are DNS querries for the scanner's IP address.

Comment: The way I see it, both Windows *and* the driver probably have a part in the problem: The driver in accessing and not letting the DNS die naturally, and Windows in letting lapse the zero-TTL DNS after a certain time (30 seconds?).

Comment: The driver software would appear to be creating the DNS lookups and then choosing not to communicate with the devices. Firstly, lookups could be massively reduced by using caching (this is the point of caching - do the devices **ever** change IP?); secondly, we have absolutely no control over the Brother software and we should not be surprised if it does some apparently odd things.